# Laravel mix / webpack not triggering the watch functionality on scripts compiling through babel()

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, babeljs, laravel-mix

We run some of our javascript files through the `babel()` functionality that Laravel mix supplies to have some backwards compatibility.

The problem we have is that if we change anything in the app.js or app.scss the watch script gets triggerd and Laravel mix automaticly compiles the correct scripts, but it does not trigger on any changes in any of the files that we feed into `babel()`. It does not matter if we run `watch` or `watch-poll`. It does compile the `babel()` scripts if we rerun watch manually, or if we run production/dev.

I have tried to find documentation on `babel()` or `watch` that explains this strange behavior. but could not find anything that explains this weird issue.

`webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
// Compile some resources independently to not include it in all pages.
.babel('resources/assets/js/cart.js', 'public/js/cart.js')
.babel('resources/assets/js/manage-addresses.js', 'public/js/manage-addresses.js')
.babel('resources/assets/js/catalog-overview-order.js', 'public/js/catalog-overview-order.js');
```

`package.json`

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
```

Software versions:

- NPM: 6.4.1
- Node.js: 8.12.0
- Webpack: 4.29.0
- Laravel: 5.5
- Laravel mix:4.0.14
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- PHP: 7.0.30
- Docker: 18.09.1, build 4c52b90

`package.json`

```html
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.5.0",
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "datatables": "^1.10.18",
        "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.19",
        "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.5.3",
        "datatables.net-plugins": "^1.10.18",
        "datatables.net-rowreorder": "^1.2.5",
        "datatables.net-rowreorder-bs4": "^1.2.5",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.14",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.16.1",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.22"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
        "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
        "bootstrap4-notify": "^4.0.3",
        "dropzone": "^5.5.1",
        "jquery-mask-plugin": "^1.14.15",
        "select2": "^4.0.5",
        "toastr": "^2.1.4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have mix.js() with some inputs piped into babel.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/cart.js', 'public/js/cart.js').babel('public/js/cart.js', 'public/js/cart.js')
```

Comment: I've spent a good hour or two looking into this issue this morning. Thank you!

Comment: An hour later and I'm still stuck. I can't use .js as I'm combining legacy code... Except when I use .combine, .scripts, or .babel watch still does nothing! If I use .js on 1 file which doesn't have any dependencies watch works, but I can't use .js for my needs. I'm so stuck

Comment: If anyone is interested,it turns out that it IS recompiling.. It's just not tellingme it is like it would when using .js

Comment: Thank you man! I was using babel() without js(), that was the issue!